# concatenation of file location for bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to improve some tsql bulk insert code by introducing a global constant:

```
declare @folder varchar(max)
declare @fileLocation varchar(max)
set @folder = 'C:\SomeFolder\'

set @fileLocation = @folder + 'Data.txt';
BULK INSERT #Table
FROM ''' + @fileLocation + '''
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

Tried every variation for the FROM code without success. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just turn it into dynamic SQL:

```
declare @folder varchar(max)
declare @fileLocation varchar(max)
set @folder = 'C:\SomeFolder\'
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @fileLocation = @folder + 'Data.txt';
set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #Table
FROM ''' + @fileLocation + '''
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
);'

exec(@sql)
```